Solved Kotlin multiplatform Gradle build faild with Invaild Timestamp Error
I was trying to setup a Kotlin multiplatform project with the multiplatform wizard from JetBrains: https://kmp.jetbrains.com, but when I tried to run the app on the emulator I get this error:
copyNonXmlValueResourcesForCommonMain task was failed:
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Invalid Timestamp -2785708036854 for 'file '/the_project_dir/composeApp/src/commonMain/composeResources/drawable''

I already tried to upgrade the gradle plugin to the newest version, but then I got a warning that kmp isn't tested with that AGP and Gradle version.
I also tried making a clean build again.
Edit:
I could actually fix it by touching the folder:
touch /the_project_dir/composeApp/src/commonMain/composeResources/drawable

I thought I already tried that...Well at least it's fixed now.

When you create a copy of your project files (not just renaming the folder, an actual duplication of all files) and try to build that project instead, does that also fail with the same error?

Please add the solution as an answer and mark it as answered
